# How to send text with space in Android UIAutomator -e command line parameter

Tags: android, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, android-uiautomator

I want to know how to send text with space in Android UIAutomator -e option (name-value pair)

For Ex:

adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings

I want to send like

adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings -e appName Temple Run

But getting error message like:

Unsupported standalone parameter.

tried like "Temple Run" or 'Temple Run' but no use.

Please suggest

Comment: Why do you even want to pass AppName like this?

Comment: hi Smriti, there are many uses. Simple example is like i want to write some jar file which will open any app by sending app name. It will search for that app name specified from Command line and will open it.

Comment: I doubt that whether app launch directly can be done through this. If you want to launch app -> you can also write code for that. Is that not working?

Comment: Pls ignore app launching etc. Its just an example and I will be able to take care of that. I need a method to pass space from command line. that is my basic issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String defaultAppName = "My super App";

    String toAppName = getParams().getString("appName"); //pass app name with 'appName' key

    if (toAppName != null) {
        toAppName = toAppName.replace("0"," "); //use 0 instead of space in app name
        defaultAppName=toAppName.trim();
    }
```

The above code will default to 'My super App' if no -e option (name-value pair) is passed when running this test.

To pass the arguments with space, like 'my super dooper app', according to the code above, 0 needs to be inserted for every space.

To pass 'my super dooper app' as an argument to the above code, one needs to send use:

```
-e appName "my0super0dooper0app"
```

In your case:

```
 adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings -e appName Temple0Run
```

(Instead of '0' you can insert any alpha numeric character as a placeholder as shown in example below)

UiAutomator fails to understand command line parameters with space, &, <, > , (,) , ", ' , as well as some Unicode characters. In such a case, one has to replace a placeholder in command line with the desired symbol.

example:

```
if (toParam != null) {
        toParam = toParam.replace("0space0", " "); //insert 0space0 in command line parameters for every space
        toParam = toParam.replace("0amper0", "&"); //insert 0amper0 in command line parameters for every &
        toParam = toParam.replace("0less0", "<"); //insert 0less0 in command line parameters for every <
        toParam = toParam.replace("0more0", ">"); //insert 0more0 in command line parameters for every >
        toParam = toParam.replace("0openbkt0", "("); //insert 0openbkt0 in command line parameters for every (
        toParam = toParam.replace("0closebkt0", ")"); //insert 0closebkt0 in command line parameters for every )
        toParam = toParam.replace("0onequote0", "'"); //insert 0onequote0 in command line parameters for every '
        toNumber = toParam.trim();
    }
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks you very much BitterPlutonium. Althought it is not a solution due to limitations from UIAUtomator code itself,  This workaround did solved my problem. Thanksalot.

Comment: @BitterPlutonium
I have created a sample project and compiled it to generate a JAR file.
However, when running using uiautomator, I'm getting the following:
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Didn't find class "test.Scree
nshotRoutine" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.run
ner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/uiautomator.jar", zip file "/data/local/tm
p/AutomaticScreenshot.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
Any help? Thanks