# how to get command line parameters with "&"

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am running uiautomator with command line parameters as following,

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest xxx.jar -c com.xxxxx -e keyString "hereisvalue&test"
```

but getParams().getString("keyString") only got "hereisvalue" instead of "hereisvalue&test", characters from "&" has been lost, how can it get the whole string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have found a solution, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709568/how-to-send-text-with-space-in-android-uiautomator-e-command-line-parameter), 
write a bash shell to replace all "&" characters,

```
${param//&/0amper0}
```

then, replace all these strings in code,

```
getParams().getString("keyString").replace("0amper0", "&");
```